# Should we subscribe to a void function and how?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, rxjs5

With promisses its easy becouse I can tell to the function that the return type of void function is Promise (I hope im right about it).

I want to do the same with Observables so it will be something like:

```
import {Observable, Subject} from "rxjs/Rx"

...
private personArray:Person[] = PERSONS; ///some persons in other file.
...

///This fucntion remove one person from my service.

public remove(id:number):Observable<void> {
    this.personArray = this.personArray.filter(person1=>person1.id !== id);
    return Observable.from(); ???
  }
```

1. The subscriber won't know if the first line throw an error. I'm sure there is a better way to do that and I will be heppy to see any other sulotions for this.
2. How can I make this code work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the OnCompleted message, use [`Observable.empty()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-empty). If an error happens, you can use [`Observable.throw(...)`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-throw):

```
public remove(id:number):Observable<void> {
  try {
    this.personArray = this.personArray.filter(person1=>person1.id !== id);
    return Observable.empty();
  } catch (e) {
    return Observable.throw(e);
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you could use [`.defer()`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-defer). If your function throws an exception, the OnError will be (automatically) thrown instead:

```
public remove(id:number):Observable<void> {
  return Observable.defer(() => {
    this.personArray = this.personArray.filter(person1=>person1.id !== id);
    return Observable.empty();
  });
}
```

Comment: Okay thanks for the quick answer. And is this the best way to implement remove? As I mentioned, the subscribers wont know if the first line in the remove fucntion returns an error.. And the observer Im using is generic so what should I import to use this one?

Comment: I see your point. Added a way to let the subscribers receive an error. Take a look.

Comment: No need to thank. I added a `.defer(function)` example. Is that closer to what you want?

Comment: Yes! But there is a little problem - Observable generic type cant be void: Error: TS2355: A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value.

Comment: In what line specifically do you get that error. Also, humm, thinking a bit more about it, maybe `.defer()` is not optimal because it will only execute when someone subscribes (that is, if you call `remove()` and don't subscribe to it, it won't execute...).

Comment: "Observable<void>" is not legal. Can't write void as a generic type.

Answer (score 0):

Since you can't really use `void` and the type doesn't really matter since no one will try to interpret any values, just use `any`:

```
public remove(id:number):Observable<any> {
    this.personArray = this.personArray.filter(person1=>person1.id !== id);
    return Observable.empty<any>();
}
```

Comment: Rxjs doesn't offer a smarter solution?  other developers can think I'm returning something and it's wrong. How would you implement it? Maby its better with promisses?

Comment: This is not a problem with RxJs.  Its a problem with the TypeScript language - it does not provide a way to use `void` as your generic type argument.  You'll encounter the same issue with promises

Comment: Thanks for response. Typescript does allow us to return new Promise<void>(()=>....). So maby best practice is to use promises when we not returning something. I hope to hear your opinion about that.